# Search word in attributedString from backword and get range Swift

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, nsrange

How do I search the space "" in an`attributedString` from the end of the string backwards and then get the range of that space?

I am getting an attributed string form an `rtf`-file and from this I divide it into multiple attributed strings so I can show those on screen as the pages.

But when I am retrieving the attributed string, for example in the range of 500, the last word of the substring is incomplete.

Below is the **`AppDelegate`** class code:

```
//  AppDelegate.swift

struct ScreenSize
{
static let SCREEN_WIDTH         = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
static let SCREEN_HEIGHT        = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH    = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH    = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
}
struct DeviceType
{
static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
static let IS_IPHONE_5          = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
static let IS_IPHONE_6          = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
static let IS_IPHONE_6P         = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
static let IS_IPAD              = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024.0
}
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var pageText:[NSAttributedString] = []
var startIndex = 0
var endIndex = 500
var divideFactor = Int()

 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS
    {
    endIndex = 700
    }
    else if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_5
    {
    endIndex = 900
    }
    else if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6
    {
    endIndex = 1300
    }
    else if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6P
    {
    endIndex = 1700
    }
    else
    {
    endIndex = 2000
    }



    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 144.0/255, green:  14.0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)

    for var i=1 ; i<=1 ; i++ {
        if let rtfPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Quran2", withExtension: "rtf") {
            let attributedStringWithRtf = NSMutableAttributedString(fileURL: rtfPath, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!

            var lengthOfRtf = attributedStringWithRtf.length
            divideFactor = Int(lengthOfRtf/endIndex)
            println(divideFactor)
            self.updateTextFont(attributedStringWithRtf) (valueFactor: divideFactor)

        }
    }

    return true
}
func updateTextFont(mystring:NSMutableAttributedString) (valueFactor:Int) {

    let screenSizeMain: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let myAttriText:NSMutableAttributedString = mystring.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
    myAttriText.beginEditing()
    myAttriText.enumerateAttributesInRange(NSMakeRange(0, myAttriText.length), options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions.Reverse) { (attribute, range, stop) -> Void in

        var mutableAttributes = NSDictionary(dictionary: attribute)
        var font:UIFont = mutableAttributes.objectForKey(NSFontAttributeName) as! UIFont
        var newFont:UIFont = font.fontWithSize(font.pointSize)

        if DeviceType.IS_IPAD
        {
            newFont = font.fontWithSize(font.pointSize+7)

        }
        var fontProperties:UIFontDescriptor = font.fontDescriptor()
        let sizeNumber:Float = fontProperties.fontAttributes()[UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute] as! Float
        myAttriText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: newFont, range: range)

    }

    for var i=0; i < valueFactor; i++ {

        let range =  NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex)
        var nsText = myAttriText.attributedSubstringFromRange(range)
        pageText.append(nsText)
        println(endIndex)

    }

    myAttriText.endEditing()

}

func visibleRangeOfTextView(textView: NSAttributedString) -> NSRange {
    return NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex)

}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```

Comment: Your question and code seem to bear little resemblance. Can you explain what you want with an example and an explanation of why you want it?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited version (following update of question)**

One way of obtaining the range of the final spaces to write a String extension.

```
extension String {

  func getMatches(regex: String, options: NSStringCompareOptions?) -> [Range<String.Index>] {
    var arr = [Range<String.Index>]()
    var rang = Range(start: self.startIndex, end: self.endIndex)
    var foundRange:Range<String.Index>?

    repeat
    {
        foundRange = self.rangeOfString(regex, options: options ?? [], range: rang, locale: nil)

        if let a = foundRange {
            arr.append(a)
            rang.startIndex = foundRange!.endIndex
        }
    }
        while foundRange != nil
    return  arr
   }

}
```

This can then be implemented as follows:

```
let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello, playground. How are you, today?")
// obtain range of final space
let ranges = attrStr.string.getMatches(" ", options: [])
let rangeOfFinalSpace = ranges[advance(ranges.endIndex, -2, ranges.startIndex)]
```

**Other Approaches**

This is a bit of a hurried reply, and the code could be stripped back further. Also worth considering is use of NSCharacterSet for whitespace and newline characters, and/or NSScanner. Reversing the string and getting the index of the whitespace before subtracting that index from the length of the string's final index might also optimise things.

**Note: the code is written in Swift 2 (Xcode 7 beta 5)**

Comment: Actually i am new to swift but getting a attributed sting in which i am sending range so because of this range the last word cut half and the other part of the word is send to next attributed string like... paragraph is the word and our range is getting "parag" in first attributed sting and start the next attributed string with word "raph". i want to get the last word complete in first string or in the second attributed string

Comment: I'm not clear if you wish to stop word breaks or search across them. Are you using the combination of UITextView, NSTextStorage, NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSAttributedString to control text flow across pages? I'm assuming the broken word is hyphenated. If it's this you wish to stop you can control hyphenation using hyphenationFactor of NSMutableParagraphStyle and NSLayoutManager. As Apple states: "When the paragraph’s hyphenation factor is 0.0, the layout manager’s hyphenation factor is used instead. When both are 0.0, hyphenation is disabled."